# Value not selected angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new in angular 6. I am just creating an angular form with validation. I have successfully implemented the validations. The only problem is the first value of the select box shows empty.
Here is code:

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.roles.errors }">
  <label>Role*</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1"  [(ngModel)]="team.roles" formControlName="roles"  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.roles.errors }">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let roles of teamRoles" value="{{roles.id}}">{{roles.admin_role}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is the component code:

```
this.teamForm = this.formBuilder.group({    
  name: ['', [Validators.required]],
  roles: ['', [Validators.required]],
  fileData: ['', [Validators.required]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)]],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  phone: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10)]],
  recovery: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
});
```

I want Please select should be selected.

Comment: You don't use ngModel with reactive forms, see https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-associating-the-formgroup-model-and-view

Comment: remove the `ngModel`

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from `[(ngModel)]="team.roles"` you are trying to bind the data of select with the whole `team.roles` list:

Try to define the selected value in your component class

```
selectRole:string = "player"
```

and in you select :

```
[(ngModel)]="selectRole"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `[(ngModel)]="team.roles"` it should work